# issues when attaching a class to tableview from the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm developing an app that has a user create part, 
i made the create account in a tableview, on the storyboard.

if i just run the simulator at that point, i see all the tableview and everything is fine.
but once i attach a class to it that extends UITableViewController, 
and i run everything in the simulator
the Screen is empty with no fields.
what am i doing wrong ? 
what do i need to look for ?

If i run it empty i see everything good in the simulator>

[image]

but once i add the class i dont see anything, but empty fields >

[image]

thanks

Comment: Have you set the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the `tableView`?

Comment: yes, both set to the tableview itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it
by modifying my Tableview method to this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        print ("section: ", section)
        if (section == 0) {
            return 4

        } else if (section == 1) {
            return 1

        } else if (section == 2) {
            return 4

        } else if (section == 3) {
            return 2

        } else if (section == 4) {
            return 1

        } else if (section == 5) {
            return 3

        } else if (section == 6) {
            return 1

        } else if (section == 7) {
            return 1

        } else {
            return 0
        }

    }
```